# Learning roadmap for constructive mathematics

Tags: reference-request, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I just watched the talk ["five stages of accepting constructive mathematics"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21qPOReu4FI). I am very interested to learn constructive mathematics but have zero knowledge of constructive mathewmatics/logic. I would like to read a book (or books ?) that begins by listing the rules of the intuitionist formal proof system, then maybe move on to doing analysis followed by some Topology maybe.

I know bishop's book seems to be a standard reference, but I don't know if it has any prerequisites (say like reading the formal proof system of intuitionism ). I also don't know if it is outdated now.

Thank you,

Comment: In set theory , the idea of constructism makes some sense to make the continuum hypothesis and the axiom of choice theorems. But apart from that , I do not think that this idea has any merit. We lose the excluded middle which prevents us to prove tons of very important and nice results. Hope you do not even want to become an ultrafinitist and deny the existence of very large numbers.

Comment: @Peter That's frankly ridiculous, and I say this as a classical mathematician. There are many reasons to be interested in constructivism and constructive mathematics. Topos theory, computability theory, and proof theory each provide separate motivations (just for a start).

Comment: To the OP, see the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383418/initiation-to-constructive-mathematics).

Comment: For an introduction which includes some philosophy and focuses on Brouwer’s school of intuitionism, consider *Elements of Intuitionism* by Dummett.

Comment: (@Peter And separately, the first sentence of your comment suggests a conflation between constructivism and Godel's constructible universe $L$, which are in fact totally unrelated: there's nothing really "constructive" about $L$ at all.)